# SIP/2.0 500 Service Unavailable issue

Tags: sip, asterisk

I am getting SIP/2.0 500 Service Unavailable, I created a sip trunk from nexmo to my server. The status is 200 ok. but when i call on that trunk through my mobile then my server is getting SIP response 500 "Service Unavailable" back from 119.XX.XX.X:5060. For detailed log please go through the attachment! Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: if i understand a nexmo is voip provider and you are trying make call from this same local network where is your asterisk is setup ?

Comment: @przeqpiciel thanks for replying. Yes we have a local asterisk server and we are trying nexmo for the first time, so we made a sip trunk between our local and nexmo server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your FreePBX server like this:

```
host=sip.nexmo.com
type=friend
insecure=port,invite
qualify=yes
allow=ulaw,alaw
dtmfmode=rfc2833
fromuser=APIKEY
secret=APISECRET

Register String
APIKEY:APISECRET@sip.nexmo.com
```

Comment: We are using same settings as described in the nexmo's documentation: [nexmo]
username=APIKEY
host=sip.nexmo.com
defaultuser= APIKEY
fromuser= APIKEY
fromdomain=sip.nexmo.com
secret= APISECRET
type=peer
context=nexmo
insecure=very
qualify=yes
nat=no
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
dtmfmode=rfc2833

register => APIKEY:APISECRET@sip.nexmo.com

Comment: and you knew all of that document? https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/sip ?
this is freepbx, right ?